# How can I get the values inside the nested database?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, body-parser

I want to get the values from the frontend to my backend using req.body. However it is not working for nested bodies and for single value it gives me undefined.

Here is my mongoose schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  chinese: {
    name: {
      type: String, 
      required: true
      },
    
    company: {
      type: String,
      required:  true,
    },  
    
  },
  other: {
    name: {
      type: String, 
      required: true
      },
    
    company: {
      type: String,
      required:  true,
    },
    madeIn:{
      type:String,
      required: true,
    },
    country:{
      type:String,
      required: false,
    },
    
  }
  ,
  productCategory: {
    mainCategory:{
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    subCategory:{
      type:String,
      required:false,
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  rating:{
    
  }
 

})


module.exports = mongoose.model('databaseEntries', DataSchema);
```

And this is how im trying to get the data from it:

```js
router.post('/secretTop', (req, res) => {
  const data = new datab()

  //data.chinese.name=Req.body.chinese.name THIS GIVES ME "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
  
  console.log(req.body.chinese)  // This gives me "undefiend"
  data.save()
    .then(() => { res.render('secretTop.pug', {msg: "Added Succesfully"}); 
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.render('secretTop.pug', {msg: "Something went wrong! Make sure no field is empty."})
}) 
})
```

I'm successfully able to run this when i put req.body like this:

```
const data = new datab(req.body)
```

I want to get all the values from the frontend separately.

I'm already using body-parser like this:

```js
//const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//const router = express.Router();
//Body Parser

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This is the front end PUG file:

```js
extends layout

block style
    style
        include ../static/style1.css
    block title
        title Dev Page | altrNATIVE

block content
    .gradiantDiv
        -var message = msg || '';
        .messages
            .succMsg
                h2=message

        .formDiv
            form(action="/secretTop" method="POST" class="myEntries")

                .country
                    .chineseLabel
                        label(for="Chinese Name") Chinese Product Name:
                        input(type="text" id="productName" name="name" )
                        
                        label(for="Chinese Company" ) Product Company Name:
                        input(type="text" id="productCompany" name="chinese.company"  )

                    .otherLabel
                        label(for="Other Name") Alternative Product Name:
                        input(type="text" id="productName" name="other.name")
                        
                        label(for="Other Company" ) Company Name:
                        input(type="text" id="productCompany" name="other.company" )

                        label(for="Other Country" ) Company Country(Optional):
                        //select#country(name='other.country')

                        label(for="Other Made In") Made in:
                        textarea( name="other.madeIn" id="textInput")
                           
                    .commonProductType
                        label(for="Product Category") Product Category:
                        input(type="text" id="productCategory" name="productCategory.mainCategory")
                        label(for="Product Category") Sub Category (Optional):
                        input(type="text" id="subCategory" name="productCategory.subCategory" )
                        
                        
                       

                button.btn Submit
```

Server: app.js

```js
const express = require('express');

const path = require('path');

const routes = require('./routes/index');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//Body Parser

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', routes)

//Static Directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static')); 
//Template Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');



module.exports = app;
```

For initializing: start.js

```js
const app = require('./app')
require('./models/database');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DataBaseMain', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(()=>{
    return console.log('MongoDB Connected...');
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));



const server = app.listen(2000, () => {
    console.log(`Express is running on port ${server.address().port}`);
  });
```

Comment: Can you show frontend part also..

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: add this before body parser `app.use(express.json())` and remove comment from express router

Comment: Shoudnt it be router.use?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. This is what i get when i do req.body.chinese.name

Comment: Just console `req.body`

Comment: Show your exact router file and main index/server file code

Comment: I have added the other server and initial js files. Also console.log(req.body) gives {
   'chinese.name': 'Demo 1',
  'chinese.company': 'Demo 2',
  'other.name': 'Demo 3',
  'other.company': 'Demo 4',
  'other.country': 'India',
  'other.madeIn': 'Demo 5',
  'productCategory.mainCategory': 'Demo 6',
  'productCategory.subCategory': 'Demo 7'
}

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of all of this:

```
app.use(express.json())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//Body Parser

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And instead do this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#express-route-specific

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

// Create `application/json` parser
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post("/api/users", jsonParser, function(request, response) { /* ... */ });
//                     ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Alternatively if you expect to receive JSON do this:

```
import { json } from "express";


app.post("/api/users", json(), function(request, response) { /* ... */ });
//                     ~~~~~~
```

I've never had a particularly good experience using `body-parser` as top-level middleware.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't do anything for me. Im really feeling motivated as I'm unable to get this right. I don't know what exactly is the problem. Could it be the schema? Thanks for answering though.

Comment: No, it very much has to do with the payload that is being sent from your frontend and the route that is receiving that payload on the backend. You're going to want to debug this using Postman and Fiddler since you could be a.) omitting the `Content-Type`, b.) sending the wrong `Content-Type`, or c.) `body-parser` could be incorrectly detecting the payload content type. Right now you have too many variables in play.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistake on view part:

You have just written `name`:

`input(type="text" id="productName" name="name" )`

It should be `chinese.name`:

`input(type="text" id="productName" name="chinese.name" )`

Comment: Sorry, it is chinese.name only i forgot to paste the recent changes. Its the same problem anyways.